# Create a common loader by intercepting http request (HttpInterceptors)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-http-interceptors

I am creating a common loader in ionic 3 but there is a problem because of manually using `loader.dismiss()`

Instead of creating a loader using `loaderCtrl` on very `http` request in ionic I'm planning to make only one loader. I am using a `httpInterceptor` and when the request is intercepted i created and present the loader. And i check if the event is of type `HttpRequest`, if yes the loader is dismissed.

This works fine when only `http` request is made on any page i.e the request is made it is intercepted the loader is presented later when the response is obtained the loader is dismissed.

But now if there are 2 request made on 1 page i gate the error of `removeView` *not Found*.

**/loaderInterceptor.ts**

```
@Injectable()
  export class HttpLoaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  headersConfig: any;
  loader: any

  constructor(public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
  Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    this.loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: "Please wait",
    });
   this.loader.present()


 return next.handle(req).pipe(tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
  if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
      this.loader.dismiss();
  }
},
  (err: any) => {
      this.loader.dismiss();
       }));

 }
}
```

The dismiss method is called twice as 2 response are obtained and the 2nd time there is no loader to be dismissed so we get an error.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In my think, the request success before loading bar reason, so I created one service use to solve it. My source code is below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoadingService {

  private loaders = [];
  private badLoaders = 0;

  constructor(
      private loadingController: LoadingController
  ) {
  }

  async startLoading() {
      if (this.badLoaders > 0) {
          this.badLoaders --;
      } else {
          await this.loadingController.create({
              message: 'Loading ...',
          }).then(loader => {
              this.loaders.push(loader);
              loader.present().then(() => {
                  if (this.badLoaders > 0) {
                      this.badLoaders --;
                      this.endLoading();
                  }
              });
          });
      }
  }

  endLoading() {
      let loader = this.loaders.pop();
      if (loader) {
          loader.dismiss();
      } else {
          this.badLoaders ++;
      }
  }

}
```

You can try it, use LoadingService.startLoading instead `this.loadingCtrl.create` and LoadingService.endLoading instead `this.loader.dismiss();`.

Comment: sorry this isnt working as this is ionic 3 and ur solution i guess is for ionic 2